# Copy ObservableCollection<myclass> to ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,object>>

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I want to know if someone can tell me an easier way to copy my `ObservableCollection<myclass>` to  `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`

this is how i do it:

```
 KeyValueCollection=new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();

 //Collection = ObservableCollection<myclass>
 foreach (var entry in Collection)
        {
             KeyValueCollection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(entry.Name,entry));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> KeyValueCollection =
          new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(collection.ToDictionary(
              entry => t.Name, 
              entry => (object)entry));
```

This creates a `Dictionary<string,object>` by selecting the `Name` property of your `myclass` as keys casting `myclass` to `object` as values.

Since `Dictionary<string,object>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` you can use it as constructor argument for the `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`.